# Error "Unable to retrieve tenant service info" from Microsoft Graph

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We use the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK to authenticate users who use O365 and to work with the users' files and folders in OneDrive and SharePoint.

Today, some of our users started receiving this error message: "Unable to retrieve tenant service info". The error code is: "BadRequest", which doesn't seem to correspond to the message and thus might just be a catch-all error code. Except for the mentioned error code and message, no other information was provided in the error response from Graph.

After some debugging, I could verify that this problem was not related to OAuth or the users' access tokens, as the users are still able to authenticate and refresh their tokens via the API. The error is only thrown when our server attempts to access or modify the users' files/folders in either OneDrive or SharePoint.

We had been using the same code for a few months, and only started receiving this error today. I've tried looking up the error message in documentation, articles, blog posts, etc. but couldn't find anything.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I get this error message too, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

There was an incident/regression that caused failures when reading tenant service info between January 19 and January 21. This should no longer be happening.

Comment: Is there any channel other than StackOverflow or GitHub where we can receive regular updates about problems in the Microsoft Graph API, as well as to report bugs/problems? It usually takes weeks to receive a response on StackOverflow and GitHub, but we need to quickly resolve any problem that arises since our clients use our product daily. Thank you.